# Getting a dependency error when installing RadRails

Tags: eclipse, plugins, aptana, pydev, radrails

I'm trying to install the Aptana RadRails/Aptana Studio plugin for Eclipse and I'm getting a strange dependency error. Here are the details:

OS: Ubuntu 11.04
Eclipse version: 3.5 (Galileo)
RadRails version: Aptana Studios Plugin version 3.0.4

Note: I also have the PyDev plugin installed

Anyway, I went to install new software in Eclipse and typed in the URL (http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install)
then checked the box for "Aptana Studio 3 plugin" and clicked next, and I got this error:

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.0.4.201108101432-7E37B7HFEHCdSHSV5R_IyJetqA_B (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.0.4.201108101432-7E37B7HFEHCdSHSV5R_IyJetqA_B)
  Software currently installed: PyDev for Eclipse 2.2.1.2011071313 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.2.1.2011071313)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.7.2010050621 (org.python.pydev 1.5.7.2010050621)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.5.2010030420 (org.python.pydev 1.5.5.2010030420)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.6.2.2010090812 (org.python.pydev 1.6.2.2010090812)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.6.1.2010080312 (org.python.pydev 1.6.1.2010080312)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 2.2.1.2011071313 (org.python.pydev 2.2.1.2011071313)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.6.5.2011020317 (org.python.pydev 1.6.5.2011020317)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.8.2010062823 (org.python.pydev 1.5.8.2010062823)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.6.2010033101 (org.python.pydev 1.5.6.2010033101)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.9.2010063001 (org.python.pydev 1.5.9.2010063001)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 2.2.2.2011082312 (org.python.pydev 2.2.2.2011082312)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.4.2010011921 (org.python.pydev 1.5.4.2010011921)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.3.1260479439 (org.python.pydev 1.5.3.1260479439)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 2.2.1.2011073123 (org.python.pydev 2.2.1.2011073123)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 2.2.0.2011062419 (org.python.pydev 2.2.0.2011062419)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.1.1258496115 (org.python.pydev 1.5.1.1258496115)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.6.4.2011010200 (org.python.pydev 1.6.4.2011010200)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.6.3.2010100513 (org.python.pydev 1.6.3.2010100513)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 2.0.0.2011040403 (org.python.pydev 2.0.0.2011040403)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 2.1.0.2011052613 (org.python.pydev 2.1.0.2011052613)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.6.0.2010071813 (org.python.pydev 1.6.0.2010071813)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.6.2.2010090711 (org.python.pydev 1.6.2.2010090711)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.9.2010063000 (org.python.pydev 1.5.9.2010063000)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.0.1251989166 (org.python.pydev 1.5.0.1251989166)
    Pydev - Python Development Environment 1.5.2.1260362205 (org.python.pydev 1.5.2.1260362205)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.0.4.201108101432-7E37B7HFEHCdSHSV5R_IyJetqA_B (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.0.4.201108101432-7E37B7HFEHCdSHSV5R_IyJetqA_B)
    To: org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group [2.2.1.2011073123]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Extensions Debug Plug-in 2.2.1.2011073123 (com.python.pydev.debug 2.2.1.2011073123)
    To: bundle org.python.pydev 2.2.1.2011073123
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PyDev for Eclipse 2.2.1.2011071313 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.2.1.2011071313)
    To: org.python.pydev [2.2.1.2011071313]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PyDev for Eclipse 2.2.1.2011073123 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.2.1.2011073123)
    To: com.python.pydev.debug [2.2.1.2011073123]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studio 3 includes PyDev by default, so you would need to uninstall the existing PyDev from the current Eclipse installation first and then install Studio 3 plugins.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Also for future reference, does the Pydev that comes with the Aptana plugin update on the same schedule as the Pydev plugin or is it on another release schedule?

Comment: They are on a different release schedule but should not be far apart.