# Installing Aptana plugin on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ftp, aptana, ubuntu-11.04

I have added the link to Aptana plugin on my Eclipse Helios Service Release 2

I couldn't install it and I think is about my PyDev plugin, can anyone help me?
I'm installing this Aptana plugin because I need FTP on Eclipse and in some link here on stack I've found this as a better option.

My Eclipse log:

```
> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.  
> Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin
> 3.0.7.201112281220-7E37K7HFGJHQUdGP8W_Iz0Jitq7M (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group
> 3.0.7.201112281220-7E37K7HFGJHQUdGP8W_Iz0Jitq7M)   Software currently installed: PyDev for Eclipse 2.3.0.2011121518
> (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.3.0.2011121518)   Only one
> of the following can be installed at once: 
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.5.2010030420 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.5.2010030420)
>     Core Plug-in 2.3.0.2011121518 (org.python.pydev.core 2.3.0.2011121518)
>     Core Plug-in 1.6.1.2010080312 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.1.2010080312)
>     Core Plug-in 2.2.2.2011082312 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.2.2011082312)
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.1.1258496115 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.1.1258496115)
>     Core Plug-in 1.6.3.2010100513 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.3.2010100513)
>     Core Plug-in 2.2.3.2011100616 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.3.2011100616)
>     Core Plug-in 2.2.4.2011110216 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.4.2011110216)
>     Core Plug-in 2.2.1.2011071313 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.1.2011071313)
>     Core Plug-in 2.1.0.2011052613 (org.python.pydev.core 2.1.0.2011052613)
>     Core Plug-in 1.6.2.2010090711 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.2.2010090711)
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.7.2010050621 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.7.2010050621)
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.2.1260362205 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.2.1260362205)
>     Core Plug-in 2.0.0.2011040403 (org.python.pydev.core 2.0.0.2011040403)
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.8.2010062823 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.8.2010062823)
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.0.1251989166 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.0.1251989166)
>     Core Plug-in 1.6.0.2010071813 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.0.2010071813)
>     Core Plug-in 1.6.4.2011010200 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.4.2011010200)
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.6.2010033101 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.6.2010033101)
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.9.2010063001 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.9.2010063001)
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.9.2010063000 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.9.2010063000)
>     Core Plug-in 1.6.5.2011020317 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.5.2011020317)
>     Core Plug-in 1.6.2.2010090812 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.2.2010090812)
>     Core Plug-in 2.2.0.2011062419 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.0.2011062419)
>     Core Plug-in 2.2.4.2011121401 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.4.2011121401)
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.4.2010011921 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.4.2010011921)
>     Core Plug-in 1.5.3.1260479439 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.3.1260479439)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.0.7.201112281220-7E37K7HFGJHQUdGP8W_Iz0Jitq7M (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group
> 3.0.7.201112281220-7E37K7HFGJHQUdGP8W_Iz0Jitq7M)
>     To: org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group [2.2.4.2011121401]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: PyDev for Eclipse 2.2.4.2011121401 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.2.4.2011121401)
>     To: org.python.pydev.core [2.2.4.2011121401]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: PyDev for Eclipse 2.3.0.2011121518 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.3.0.2011121518)
>     To: org.python.pydev.core [2.3.0.2011121518]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> try running Studio from command line with the -clean flag to clean the cached configurations.
>
> or if It turns out the issue with conflicting dependency when updating normally has to do with Studio being installed into Program Files directory. In that case, updating will only work if Studio is run as Administrator due to an Eclipse restriction. Please see the wiki page here: [http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Miscellaneous#Miscellaneou....](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Miscellaneous#Miscellaneous-Conflictdependency)

hope that helps

Comment: Hi Mido, thanks for your reply, I'm running on Linux(Ubuntu 11.04), I don't know if -clean is a flag on Ubuntu for Eclipse but I tried it on terminal, eclipse opened normally but same results, same error log...

Comment: Hey Gerep, well, i am running on Ubuntu 11.10.
take a look at this thread. i think it is the same problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441085/getting-a-dependency-error-when-installing-radrails

Comment: It was installed but I can't find the FTP option, not even to configure..can you help me?

Comment: As mentioned in the thread Mido referred to, you would need to uninstall PyDev first (Help > About Eclipse SDK > Installation Details) and then install Aptana Studio since Aptana Studio 3 includes PyDev by default.